# use `Buildfile` to build typescript on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nodes

I'm trying to build Typescript on AWS EB. Based on documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html ) `Buildfile` suppose to be used for build. But I guess it's not running at all.

This is image which is used for my EB: `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.4.5 running Node.js 14`

Here is rest of the info:

```
server
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┗ index.ts
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ Buildfile
 ┣ build.sh
 ┣ mkzip.sh
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┣ package.json
 ┗ tsconfig.json
```

Here is my file structure.

Buildfile
`make: ./build.sh`

build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run build
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "10.0.2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean &&  tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^3.3.0",
    "graphql": "^15.6.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Any ideas what to check?

Comment: looking for the answer too... as far as I can see in Beanstalk [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-configuration-procfile.html), NodeJS only supports Procfile